# Generating buttons in a grid

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, onclicklistener

I'm working on a drum machine and I am not sure how to approach making the squares clickable. How can I alter the color of a specific square to crimson upon being clicked?

```js
const drums = ["Crash", "CHiHat", "OHiHat", "Tom3", "Tom2", "Tom1", "Snare", "Kick"];

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (let v = 0; v < 16; v++) {
      var block = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var context = block.getContext('2d');
      context.strokeRect(100 + (55 * v), (55 * i), 50, 50);
      context.fillStyle = 'crimson';
      context.fillRect(100 + (55 * v), (55 * i), 50, 50);
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
```

I tried `addEventListener`, but that returned an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A canvas is just a grid of pixels. You can't assign a click handler to a canvas shape, because that shape is just some pixels. If you aren't restricted to using canvas, try using regular elements, like this:

```js
var drumMachine = document.getElementById("drumMachine");
var nRows = 8;
var nCols = 16;

for (let i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  for (let j = 0; j < nCols; j++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.className = "clickable";
    cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
      this.classList.toggle("activated");
    });
    row.appendChild(cell);
  }
  drumMachine.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
#drumMachine {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.clickable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.clickable.activated {
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<table id="drumMachine"></table>
```

This does a few things.

1. First, it defines the grid dimensions and then creates the elements in a two-dimensional loop.
2. It then adds an click event listener to each element (here is where HTML elements shine against HTML canvas!)
3. After which, the elements are assembled into a regular table setup. CSS is used to mimic your canvas setup.

If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask in the comments.